# nginx rewrite to remove /index.html and keep query string and hash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, .htaccess, nginx

My nginx config sets `index      index.html` as its index page.

When it is opened as a progressive web app (using angular), for some reason it loads `/index.html#/route` instead of `/#/route`.

I would like to:

1. Detect if the URL contains `/index.html'`, and
2. rewrite to remove `/index.html` to correct the URL.

Is this possible in nginx or should I do this in javascript instead?

I've found [articles](http://www.woolie.co.uk/article/redirect-index-html-to-its-parent-directory-nginx/) and answers here but they don't seem to account for hash tags and query string params which are important to preserve.

Answer (score 2):

You need a better Regex Pattern (based on the article).

```
rewrite ^(?:.*\/)index.html(.*) /$1 permanent;
```

It captures the URL just after .html and the first group is a not capturing one.

Substitutions:

```
/index.html#/route    /#/route
/index.html#something    /#something
```